# Can concurrent Inserts result in such a way

Tags: mysql, innodb

I think I am having some problems related to concurrent inserts so I wanted to know if such concurrent insert statements -

```
insert into table1 (field1,field2,field3) Values (A,B,C);
insert into table1 (field1,field2,field3) Values (1,2,3);
```

could result in a row like

```
A B 3
```

A and B from the first insert statement and the 3 from the second insert statement. My table is using InnoDB storage btw.

Comment: No, this cannot occur. Unless you have an extremely buggy version of the pre-alpha 0.00001 version of InnoDB... which is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Inserts and updates normally lock the tables/row they are operating on so that won't happen.

Comment: A table lock for an INSERT? Even with InnoDB? That sounds scary.